# coloured matrix R save latex

Tags: r, image, matrix, import, latex

I have this "coloured" matrix in R

```
library(gplots)

#Build the matrix data to look like a correlation matrix
x <- matrix(rnorm(64), nrow=8)
x <- (x - min(x))/(max(x) - min(x)) #Scale the data to be between 0 and 1
for (i in 1:8) x[i, i] <- 1.0 #Make the diagonal all 1's

#Format the data for the plot
xval <- formatC(x, format="f", digits=2)
pal <- colorRampPalette(c(rgb(0.96,0.96,1), rgb(0.1,0.1,0.9)), space = "rgb")

#Plot the matrix
x_hm <- heatmap.2(x, Rowv=FALSE, Colv=FALSE, dendrogram="none", main="8 X 8 Matrix Using Heatmap.2", xlab="Columns", ylab="Rows", col=pal, tracecol="#303030", trace="none", cellnote=xval, notecol="black", notecex=0.8, keysize = 1.5, margins=c(5, 5))
```

and I would like to import it in Latex. How can I do?
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

`gplots::heatmap.2` only prints the image of a colored matrix, it doesn't actually return one. Nevertheless, we can recreate it ourselves and convert it into a latex table (although the comment of saving the image and using `\includegraphics`in latex is just as good). Here's the .Rmd file you can use. Make sure to Knit as a PDF!

````
---
title: "Hey Stack"
header-includes:
   - \usepackage[table]{xcolor}
output: pdf_document
---

```{r, include = FALSE}
library(gplots)
library(xtable)

#Build the matrix data to look like a correlation matrix
x <- matrix(rnorm(64), nrow=8)
x <- (x - min(x))/(max(x) - min(x)) #Scale the data to be between 0 and 1
for (i in 1:8) x[i, i] <- 1.0 #Make the diagonal all 1's

#Format the data for the plot
xval <- formatC(x, format="f", digits=2)
pal <- colorRampPalette(c(rgb(0.96,0.96,1), rgb(0.1,0.1,0.9)), space = "rgb")

x_hm <- heatmap.2(x, Rowv=FALSE, Colv=FALSE, dendrogram="none", 
  main="8 X 8 Matrix Using Heatmap.2", xlab="Columns", ylab="Rows", col=pal,
  tracecol="#303030", trace="none", cellnote=xval, notecol="black", notecex=0.8, 
  keysize = 1.5, margins=c(5, 5))
```

```{r, results = 'asis'}
color_m <- apply(round(x, 2), 2, function(r) {
  col <- cut(r, x_hm$breaks, gsub("#", "", x_hm$col), include.lowest = TRUE) 

  paste0("\\cellcolor[HTML]{", col, "}{", r, "}")
})

print(xtable(color_m), sanitize.text.function = identity, comment = FALSE, 
      include.rownames = FALSE, include.colnames = FALSE)
```
````

Comment: Wish I could give more upvotes for this answer. Marking via this comment so I can find it in a couple of days and lay up a bonus.